# I'm confused by a simple regex: I need to match something like [Test] but not Test

Tags: regex

How would I go about writing a regex to match the first example, but not the second?

Thank you --

Comment: `\[Test\]` should do it...?

Comment: basic knowledge about regular expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\[Test\]
```

You need to escape the `[` and `]` as they indicate range start/end.

Comment: It's fun, racing for the points :-)

Answer (score 3):

`[]` are special characters for a regex, used for defining a character class, therefore escape them with backslashes.

```
\[Test\]
```

If you use `[Test]`, it will match a single character which is either `T`, `e`, `s` or `t`.